# Inferring Parameter Types from Usage when Generating Typescript Declarations from JS Files in

Tags: javascript, typescript, declaration, tsc

I'd like to be able to generate `.d.ts` files but ALSO infer some parameters from usage in source files. The tsc command below generates a `.d.ts` but all params are typed as `any`. I want to tell it to infer from usage similar to how `VSCode` allows you to do so (see GIF below)

```
tsc node_modules/three-bmfont-text/index.js --declaration --allowJs --emitDeclarationOnly --outDir mytypes
```

[image: VSCode code action that infers parameters types from usage]

Any idea how to do that? I've tried npm modules that claim to do that (like `dtsmake` but I have yet to be successful.